# Reoccurring SQL job to run on the 2nd and 4th Thursday of every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I need a job to run on the 2nd and 4th Thursday of every month. I know I can set up a job to run every two weeks but that logic doesn't work when a month eventually hits a five week span. Is it possible to set this up using the SQL Server Agent Schedule? If not, does anyone recommend another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two schedules on the job, one that runs on the second Thursday, and one that runs on the fourth.

Under the `Frequency` heading on the Scheduler, change the `Occurs` drop down to `Monthly` to get to the options you need.

Comment: I just noticed this!! Thank you Eric!