# Custom SQL Schedule to Execute Command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way to run a SQL command twice a month following this logic:

Run on the Thursday following the 2nd Tuesday of the month

And

Run on the Thursday following the 4th Tuesday of the month

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reoccurring SQL job to run on the 2nd and 4th Thursday of every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536096/reoccurring-sql-job-to-run-on-the-2nd-and-4th-thursday-of-every-month)

Comment: Also, what happens when there is no Thursday following the 4th Tuesday of the month (for example February).

Comment: This is really no different from your previous question. You just lack imagination to use the features your chosen scheduler (agent presumably) to accomplish your goal. You can schedule a job for every day and simply check for the appropriate conditions and do nothing when it is not "time". You can schedule it for every thursday. Not many apps will provide this specific logic - think outside the box.

Comment: @SMor The question is completely different. You even answered with a possible solution so thank you. Please try to remember that not everyone here is as advanced as others. It has nothing to do with imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Running this everyday will do the trick

```
    IF (
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(
      Month, 
      DATEDIFF(
        Month, 
        0, 
        GETDATE()
      ), 
      0
    ) + 6 + 7 - (
      DATEPART(
        Weekday, 
        DATEADD(
          Month, 
          DATEDIFF(
            Month, 
            0, 
            GETDATE()
          ), 
          0
        )
      ) + (@@DateFirst + 3) + 7
    ) % 7 + 2
) -- Thursday after SECOND tuesday IN the this month
= GETDATE() 
OR (
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(
      Month, 
      DATEDIFF(
        Month, 
        0, 
        GETDATE()
      ), 
      0
    ) + 6 + 21 - (
      DATEPART(
        Weekday, 
        DATEADD(
          Month, 
          DATEDIFF(
            Month, 
            0, 
            GETDATE()
          ), 
          0
        )
      ) + (@@DateFirst + 3) + 21
    ) % 7 + 2
) = GETDATE() -- Thursday after FOURTH tuesday IN the this month
```